# Как подменить null-значения у JSON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть [json](/questions/tagged/json) с отсутствующими значениями. Уровень вложенности может любой, а заменить нужно все `null` на `[]`.

Исходная [json](/questions/tagged/json):

```
{
    "Action-bar": null,
    "Action": "Action",
    "Children": [
        {"Action": null},
        {"Action": true},
        {"Action": "false"},
        {"Action": {"need": null}}
    ],
    "RGB-bar": null
}
```

```
import json

genre_translate = json.load(
    open('genre_translate.json', encoding='utf-8')
)
...
```

Нужно получить:

```
{
    "Action-bar": [],
    "Action": "Action",
    "Children": [
        {
            "Action": []
        },
        {
            "Action": true
        },
        {
            "Action": "false"
        },
        {
            "Action": {
                "need": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "RGB-bar": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что для этой задачи самым правильным решением будет не через рекурсию, а через работу с параметром `object_pairs_hook` у [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load).

В `object_pairs_hook` нужно передать функцию, что примет список из кортежей на два элемента ключ и значение, например в JSON из вопроса это будут такие значения:

```
[('Action', None)]
[('Action', True)]
[('Action', 'false')]
[('need', None)]
[('Action', {'need': None})]
...
```

А вернуть нужно словарь.

Из этого получается функция, что сформирует словарь, заменив `None`-объекты питона на `[]`:

```
import json

def dict_clean(items, default):
    return {
        k: default if v is None else v
        for k, v in items
    }

genre_translate = json.load(
    open('genre_translate.json', encoding='utf-8'),
    object_pairs_hook=lambda items: dict_clean(items, default=[])
)
print(genre_translate)
# {'Action-bar': [], 'Action': 'Action', 'Children': [{'Action': []}, {'Action': True}, {'Action': 'false'}, {'Action': {'need': []}}], 'RGB-bar': []}
```

---

**PS.**

Пример замены на `"<null>"`:

```
genre_translate = json.load(
    open('genre_translate.json', encoding='utf-8'),
    object_pairs_hook=lambda items: dict_clean(items, default="<null>")
)
print(genre_translate)
# {'Action-bar': '<null>', 'Action': 'Action', 'Children': [{'Action': '<null>'}, {'Action': True}, {'Action': 'false'}, {'Action': {'need': '<null>'}}], 'RGB-bar': '<null>'}
```